# Get the first key in an associative array

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the first key of an array in an associative array like below. I know I can use `key`, but I read (on this site), that's it's less efficient.

So I'm using `current(array_keys($data))`.

Is there another way of doing this? Will I always get the first key when I use `current(array_keys($data))`? That's what I scared off.

I'm using php 5.3.18. This is the way the script starts off.

```
<?php
$json = '{"user":"norman","city":"san jose","type":"editor"}';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

echo current(array_keys($data));
//Output I need is "user"
?>
```

Comment: Efficiency is really meaningless in this context. It might become an issue if you do tens or hundreds of thousands of elements, but not before. Do whatever makes you code better readable

Comment: The `array_keys($data)` creates a new array with the pointer set to the first element; so calling `current()` on that will always return the first entry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo current(array_keys($data));` is a long process just use `key`

```
 echo key($data);
```

Note

`$data = json_decode($json, true);` would reset the array  ... so no need to call `reset` again

Comment: Key is guaranteed to give you the first one always? In this case "user"

Comment: `$data = json_decode($json, true);` would reset that array to the first element yes .. its guaranteed

Answer (score 3):

Try with this code:

```
reset($data);
$first_key = key($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Now on PHP 7.3 >=

```
$firstKey = array_key_first($data);
```